# xcodebuild build command fails in Xcode 11.4 but not in Xcode 11.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, xcodebuild

I'm not really sure what to do here except just keep using Xcode 11.3. For reference the project is build with SwiftUI. It compiles fine in Xcode either version but not from the command line.

If I run this command while using Xcode 11.3 it works great:

```
xcodebuild build -project WorkOrders.xcodeproj -scheme "Work Orders - Production" -derivedDataPath /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData -configuration "Production Release" DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES
```

However in Xcode 11.4 it fails with the following:

```
Command line invocation:
    "/Applications/Xcode 11.4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild" build -project WorkOrders.xcodeproj -scheme "Work Orders - Production" -derivedDataPath /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData -configuration "Production Release" DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES

User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData

Build settings from command line:
    DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
CreateBuildDirectory /tmp/WorkOrders.dst (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    builtin-create-build-directory /tmp/WorkOrders.dst

CreateBuildDirectory /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    builtin-create-build-directory /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products

CreateBuildDirectory /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    builtin-create-build-directory /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex

MkDir /tmp/WorkOrders.dst/Applications/Work\ Orders.app (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    /bin/mkdir -p /tmp/WorkOrders.dst/Applications/Work\ Orders.app

SymLink /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production\ Release-iphoneos/Work\ Orders.app /tmp/WorkOrders.dst/Applications/Work\ Orders.app (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    /bin/ln -sfh /tmp/WorkOrders.dst/Applications/Work\ Orders.app /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production\ Release-iphoneos/Work\ Orders.app

ProcessProductPackaging /Users/garett/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/a2bdf7ea-5685-4d15-93fa-bd156839e4d5.mobileprovision /tmp/WorkOrders.dst/Applications/Work\ Orders.app/embedded.mobileprovision (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    builtin-productPackagingUtility /Users/garett/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/a2bdf7ea-5685-4d15-93fa-bd156839e4d5.mobileprovision -o /tmp/WorkOrders.dst/Applications/Work\ Orders.app/embedded.mobileprovision

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources/Entitlements.plist (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources/Entitlements.plist

ProcessProductPackaging "" /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders.app.xcent (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios


Entitlements:

{
    "application-identifier" = "xxxxxxxx.com.cuwcd.work-orders";
    "com.apple.developer.team-identifier" = xxxxxxxxx;
    "com.apple.security.application-groups" =     (
        "group.com.cuwcd.shared",
        "group.com.cuwcd.shared.test"
    );
    "get-task-allow" = 1;
}


    builtin-productPackagingUtility -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders.app.xcent

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/all-product-headers.yaml (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/all-product-headers.yaml

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders.hmap (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders.hmap

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-project-headers.hmap (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-project-headers.hmap

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-own-target-headers.hmap (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-own-target-headers.hmap

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-all-target-headers.hmap (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-all-target-headers.hmap

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-generated-files.hmap (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-generated-files.hmap

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WorkOrders-OutputFileMap.json (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WorkOrders-OutputFileMap.json

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Work\ Orders.SwiftFileList (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Work\ Orders.SwiftFileList

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Work\ Orders.LinkFileList (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    write-file /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Work\ Orders.LinkFileList

CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode 11.4.app/Contents/Developer"
    export SDKROOT="/Applications/Xcode 11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk"
    /Applications/Xcode\ 11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name Work_Orders -O -whole-module-optimization -enforce-exclusivity=checked @/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Work\ Orders.SwiftFileList -sdk /Applications/Xcode\ 11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios13.2 -g -module-cache-path /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -embed-bitcode-marker -swift-version 5 -I /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production\ Release-iphoneos -F /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production\ Release-iphoneos -F /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios/Carthage/Build/iOS -c -num-threads 4 -output-file-map /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WorkOrders-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Work_Orders.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production\ Release-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Work_Orders-Swift.h -working-directory /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios

CompileSwift normal arm64 (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
    cd /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios
    /Applications/Xcode\ 11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/p0/d977974s4vq_3xqjv71sc1gm0000gn/T/sources-c7613c -supplementary-output-file-map /var/folders/p0/d977974s4vq_3xqjv71sc1gm0000gn/T/supplementaryOutputs-4035df -target arm64-apple-ios13.2 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -stack-check -sdk /Applications/Xcode\ 11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk -I /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production\ Release-iphoneos -F /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production\ Release-iphoneos -F /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios/Carthage/Build/iOS -g -module-cache-path /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -O -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work\ Orders-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production\ Release-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production\ Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources -module-name Work_Orders -num-threads 4 -output-filelist /var/folders/p0/d977974s4vq_3xqjv71sc1gm0000gn/T/outputs-c8e218 -embed-bitcode-marker
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode 11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/p0/d977974s4vq_3xqjv71sc1gm0000gn/T/sources-c7613c -supplementary-output-file-map /var/folders/p0/d977974s4vq_3xqjv71sc1gm0000gn/T/supplementaryOutputs-4035df -target arm64-apple-ios13.2 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -stack-check -sdk /Applications/Xcode 11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk -I /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production Release-iphoneos -F /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production Release-iphoneos -F /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios/Carthage/Build/iOS -g -module-cache-path /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -O -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work Orders-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work Orders-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work Orders-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/Work Orders-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Products/Production Release-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorder-ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WorkOrders.build/Production Release-iphoneos/WorkOrders.build/DerivedSources -module-name Work_Orders -num-threads 4 -output-filelist /var/folders/p0/d977974s4vq_3xqjv71sc1gm0000gn/T/outputs-c8e218 -embed-bitcode-marker
1.  Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)
2.  Contents of /var/folders/p0/d977974s4vq_3xqjv71sc1gm0000gn/T/sources-c7613c:
---
...
---
3.  While emitting SIL for getter for body (at /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios/Sources/Views/Details/Work Order Details/Notes/NotesView.swift:14:9)
4.  While silgen emitFunction SIL function "@$s11Work_Orders9NotesViewV4bodyQrvg".
 for getter for body (at /Users/garett/src/cuwcd/workorders-ios/Sources/Views/Details/Work Order Details/Notes/NotesView.swift:14:9)
0  swift                    0x0000000111a0c4ea PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000111a0bcc0 SignalHandler(int) + 352
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6e7c15fd _sigtramp + 29
3  swift                    0x000000010d9e20e0 swift::ProtocolConformanceRef llvm::function_ref<swift::ProtocolConformanceRef (swift::CanType, swift::Type, swift::ProtocolDecl*)>::callback_fn<swift::ReplaceOpaqueTypesWithUnderlyingTypes>(long, swift::CanType, swift::Type, swift::ProtocolDecl*) + 0
4  swift                    0x000000010dc461c8 (anonymous namespace)::Transform::transform(swift::Lowering::ManagedValue, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern, swift::CanType, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern, swift::CanType, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 12680
5  swift                    0x000000010dc43028 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitOrigToSubstValue(swift::SILLocation, swift::Lowering::ManagedValue, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern, swift::CanType, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 136
6  swift                    0x000000010dbc3886 swift::Lowering::Conversion::emit(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction&, swift::SILLocation, swift::Lowering::ManagedValue, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) const + 710
7  swift                    0x000000010db6582d (anonymous namespace)::ScalarResultPlan::finish(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction&, swift::SILLocation, swift::CanType, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::Lowering::ManagedValue>&) + 1021
8  swift                    0x000000010db80c28 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitApply(std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::Lowering::ResultPlan, std::__1::default_delete<swift::Lowering::ResultPlan> >&&, swift::Lowering::ArgumentScope&&, swift::SILLocation, swift::Lowering::ManagedValue, swift::SubstitutionMap, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::Lowering::ManagedValue>, swift::Lowering::CalleeTypeInfo const&, swift::Lowering::ApplyOptions, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 1784
9  swift                    0x000000010db8e7bf (anonymous namespace)::CallEmission::apply(swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 3951
10 swift                    0x000000010db8ac47 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitApplyExpr(swift::ApplyExpr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 2567
11 swift                    0x000000010db864f5 (anonymous namespace)::ArgEmitter::emit(swift::Lowering::ArgumentSource&&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern) + 3701
12 swift                    0x000000010db823b3 (anonymous namespace)::ArgEmitter::emitSingleArg(swift::Lowering::ArgumentSource&&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern) + 163
13 swift                    0x000000010db946ce (anonymous namespace)::ArgEmitter::emitPreparedArgs(swift::Lowering::PreparedArguments&&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern) + 238
14 swift                    0x000000010db94549 (anonymous namespace)::CallSite::emit(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, (anonymous namespace)::ParamLowering&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::Lowering::ManagedValue>&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<(anonymous namespace)::DelayedArgument>&, llvm::Optional<swift::ForeignErrorConvention> const&, swift::ImportAsMemberStatus) && + 537
15 swift                    0x000000010db92208 (anonymous namespace)::CallEmission::emitArgumentsForNormalApply(swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::FunctionType>&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern&, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, llvm::Optional<swift::ForeignErrorConvention> const&, swift::ImportAsMemberStatus, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::Lowering::ManagedValue>&, llvm::Optional<swift::SILLocation>&, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::FunctionType>&) + 1032
16 swift                    0x000000010db8e6b8 (anonymous namespace)::CallEmission::apply(swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 3688
17 swift                    0x000000010db8ac47 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitApplyExpr(swift::ApplyExpr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 2567
18 swift                    0x000000010db864f5 (anonymous namespace)::ArgEmitter::emit(swift::Lowering::ArgumentSource&&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern) + 3701
19 swift                    0x000000010db823b3 (anonymous namespace)::ArgEmitter::emitSingleArg(swift::Lowering::ArgumentSource&&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern) + 163
20 swift                    0x000000010db946ce (anonymous namespace)::ArgEmitter::emitPreparedArgs(swift::Lowering::PreparedArguments&&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern) + 238
21 swift                    0x000000010db94549 (anonymous namespace)::CallSite::emit(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, (anonymous namespace)::ParamLowering&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::Lowering::ManagedValue>&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<(anonymous namespace)::DelayedArgument>&, llvm::Optional<swift::ForeignErrorConvention> const&, swift::ImportAsMemberStatus) && + 537
22 swift                    0x000000010db92208 (anonymous namespace)::CallEmission::emitArgumentsForNormalApply(swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::FunctionType>&, swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern&, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, llvm::Optional<swift::ForeignErrorConvention> const&, swift::ImportAsMemberStatus, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::Lowering::ManagedValue>&, llvm::Optional<swift::SILLocation>&, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::FunctionType>&) + 1032
23 swift                    0x000000010db8e6b8 (anonymous namespace)::CallEmission::apply(swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 3688
24 swift                    0x000000010db8ac47 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitApplyExpr(swift::ApplyExpr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 2567
25 swift                    0x000000010dbe2b9a swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void, void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 22410
26 swift                    0x000000010dbdd223 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitExprInto(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::Initialization*, llvm::Optional<swift::SILLocation>) + 131
27 swift                    0x000000010dc61c1d swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitReturnExpr(swift::SILLocation, swift::Expr*) + 845
28 swift                    0x000000010dc5d2fe swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtEmitter, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 12590
29 swift                    0x000000010dc5a316 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtEmitter, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 326
30 swift                    0x000000010dc0cfdf swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 799
31 swift                    0x000000010db731b9 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 953
32 swift                    0x000000010dc6ea18 void llvm::function_ref<void (swift::AccessorDecl*)>::callback_fn<(anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::visitAccessors(swift::AbstractStorageDecl*)::'lambda'(swift::AccessorDecl*)>(long, swift::AccessorDecl*) + 24
33 swift                    0x000000010dc6e97c (anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::visitVarDecl(swift::VarDecl*) + 1948
34 swift                    0x000000010dc6b53b (anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::emitType() + 1163
35 swift                    0x000000010db7d5e2 swift::ASTVisitor<swift::Lowering::SILGenModule, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Decl*) + 82
36 swift                    0x000000010db7c7ac swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*) + 1356
37 swift                    0x000000010db7e88a swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::Lowering::TypeConverter&, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit*) + 1530
38 swift                    0x000000010d7603cb swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 55595
39 swift                    0x000000010d6d64d3 main + 1283
40 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff6e5c8cc9 start + 1
41 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000003e start + 2443408246
error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')

<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal 11 (use -v to see invocation)
warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: Cannot Load File: Failed to open diagnostics file (in target 'WorkOrders' from project 'WorkOrders')
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

Comment: Isn’t that a compiler crash? Probably worth checking the Github repo or Jira system to see if anyone else has reported the issue.

Comment: Is it built within Xcode IDE? Would you show NotesView.swift?

Comment: Yeah it builds fine with the Xcode IDE but the command line tools fail to build. It also builds fine when in development mode but when I use the production scheme it fails. It's weird.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh is that the Github repo for Xcode or for the command line tools? I didn't realize there was a Github repo at all

Comment: same here any solution?

Comment: Nothing yet. I'm just using Xcode 11.3 until I have time to look into it

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Xcode 11.5. Never figured out the problem but it's working for me now

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed in Xcode 11.5